Can I Ignore Warnings about Overriding Inherited Automatic Tuning Settings (Create Index/Drop Index)?
Azure SQL Automatic Tuning has these three options with Azure defaults:

Force Plan--On
Create Index--Off
Drop Index--Off

When attempting to enable all three options, I got the following warning:
It is recommended to allow Azure to set the automatic tuning configuration by inheriting from Azure.
Are the Create/Drop index options not recommended for use?  I can't find any documentation that recommends against using these features.  That said, I don't see a good reason for this warning if those features work as advertised.
Can I ignore this warning?

Yes, you can ignore the warning. You can either manually apply tuning recommendations using the Azure portal, or you can let automatic tuning autonomously apply tuning recommendations for you.
But:
The benefits of letting the system autonomously apply tuning recommendations for you is that it automatically validates there exists a positive gain to workload performance, and if there is no significant performance improvement detected or if performance regresses, the system automatically reverts the changes that were made.
See Automatic tuning in Azure SQL Database and Azure SQL Managed Instance
